# Haskell expression type?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning some Haskell and I can't understand something. I have this expression:

```
flip foldr id
```

And I needed to find its type. After a long time trying to solve this, I gave up and looked up the correct answer, which is:

```
(a -> (a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> a1) -> [a] -> a1 -> a1
```

But I can't understand why, and I would like to! 
I guess that the `[a] -> a1 -> a1` comes from the `foldr` expression, but I don't know how to proceed.
Thank you, and sorry for my English!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Examine the types of the individual functions involved:

```
λ :t id
id :: a -> a
λ :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
λ :t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

Then try thinking of applying the functions to each other to see how the types would match up.

To avoid name conflicts when thinking, we can rewrite `flip`'s type as `(a1 -> b1 -> c1) -> b1 -> a1 -> c1`.

The first thing that happens is applying `flip` to `foldr`. Looking at the types of `flip` and `foldr`, we see that the type `a1 -> b1 -> c1` in `flip`'s type gets "matched up" with the type of `foldr`. This means `a1` matches up with `a -> b -> b`, `b1` matches up with `b`, and `c1` matches up with `[a] -> b`.

So in the context of this, `flip`'s type becomes `((a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b) -> b -> (a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b` (I just replaced each `a1` with `a -> b -> c`, each `b1` with `b` , and each `c1` with `[a] -> b`), and the type of `flip foldr` is the same thing with the first parameter taken away: `b -> (a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b`.

We can check our work so far with ghci:

```
λ :t flip foldr
flip foldr :: b -> (a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b
```

Now we take this type and apply it to the type of `id` (which we'll write as `a2 -> a2`). This means `b` matches up with `a2 -> a2`, and the type of `flip foldr` becomes `(a2 -> a2) -> (a -> (a2 -> a2) -> (a2 -> a2)) -> [a] -> (a2 -> a2)`, and the type of `flip foldr id` is the same thing with the first parameter taken away: `(a -> (a2 -> a2) -> (a2 -> a2)) -> [a] -> a2 -> a2`. This is the same as the answer you got if we just rewrite `a2` as `a1` and remove some parentheses.

Comment: I don't get to which function is flip applied.

Comment: In `flip foldr id`, `foldr` and `id` are being passed as the first and second arguments to `flip`, or, alternatively, `id` is being passed as the argument to the result of `flip foldr`.

Comment: @DemianArdus Function application is left-associative, so this means that `flip foldr id` is the same as `(flip foldr) id`. Because of how function application works in haskell, that's also like `foldr` and `id` both being passed to `flip`.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but how do you aply flip to foldr if foldr takes 3 parameters?

Comment: @DemianArdus `foldr` can also be thought of as a function that takes 2 parameters (of types `a -> b -> b` and `b`) and returns a function of type `[a] -> b`.